# C++ event handling interface with function pointers

Tags: c++, function, events, pointers, handler

I want to implement a simple event interface with function pointers for a simple game in C++. This will be done to improve the event interface of the allegro lib. Therefore I've written the following code but it doesn't work.

```
typedef void (*event_handler)(int); //type for the event handler
const int TESTKEY_A = 1; // example Key as event arg

class Game
{
      private:
              bool is_running ;
      protected:
               event_handler on_key_down[2];
      public:
               void run();
               void do_events(int e) ;
               void stop() {is_running = false;}
};
void Game::run()
{
    is_running=true; 
    while(is_running) 
        do_events(1);
}

void Game::do_events(int e) 
{
    if(e==1) 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 2 ;i++)
            on_key_down[i](TESTKEY_A);
    }
}

class Pong_Game : public Game
{
      public:
               Pong_Game();
               void On_Key_Down_Player1(int key) { return;}
               void On_Key_Down_Player2(int key) { return;}
};

Pong_Game::Pong_Game()
{
    on_key_down[0] = &this->On_Key_Down_Player1;
    on_key_down[1] = &this->On_Key_Down_Player2;
}

int main()
{
    Game *my_game = new Pong_Game();
    my_game->run();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler log:

```
Compiler: Default compiler
Executing  g++.exe...
g++.exe "U:\Eigene Dateien\eventhandler.cpp" -o "U:\Eigene Dateien\eventhandler.exe"    -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\include"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\backward"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include"   -L"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib" 
U:\Eigene Dateien\eventhandler.cpp: In constructor `Pong_Game::Pong_Game()':
U:\Eigene Dateien\eventhandler.cpp:45: error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say `&Pong_Game::On_Key_Down_Player1'
U:\Eigene Dateien\eventhandler.cpp:45: error: cannot convert `void (Pong_Game::*)(int)' to `void (*)(int)' in assignment
U:\Eigene Dateien\eventhandler.cpp:46: error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say `&Pong_Game::On_Key_Down_Player2'
U:\Eigene Dateien\eventhandler.cpp:46: error: cannot convert `void (Pong_Game::*)(int)' to `void (*)(int)' in assignment

Execution terminated
```

EDIT: 
      - changed code
      - added compiler log

Thank you!

Comment: You need to tell us how *it doesn't work*!

Comment: "It doesn't work." How? Compiler error? Linker error? Crash? Unexpected behaviour (and what is expected behaviour)? We're not magicians here.

Comment: As mentioned please provide more details of the problems you are facing and someone may be able to answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are using a member function to initialize a "plain" function pointer. Member functions are different from "plain" functions in that they have a hidden `T *this` passed along with the function.
2. This seems like something that would be MUCH better solved by having a "event handler" interface, implemented by inheritance, than using function pointers.

Something like this:

```
class Game
{
    private:
        bool is_running ;
    public:
        void run(){is_running=true; while(is_running) do_events(1);}
        void do_events(int e) {if(e==1) On_Key_Down(TESTKEY_A);}
        void stop() {is_running = false;}

        virtual void On_Key_Down(int key) = 0;
        ... other event handlers here ... 
};

class Pong_Game : public Game
{
    public:
        void Pong_Game() {}
        void On_Key_Down(int key) { // handle key event...}
        ... other event handlers here ... 
};
```

As per comments:
To cover multiple players, you may want to implement a "per player event handling":

```
class Player 
{
  public:
    enum moves { move_up, 
                 move_down, 
                 move_left, 
                 move_right, 
                 move_jump, 
                 move_shoot, ...  }; 

    ... 
    virtual void On_Key_Down(int key) = 0;
    ... 
};

class Player_A
{
   public:
    ...
    virtual moves On_Key_Down(int key) { if (key == 'W') return move_up;  ...  }
}

class Player_B
{
   public:
    ...
    virtual moves On_Key_Down(int key) { if (key == 'I') return move_up;  ...  }
}


class Pong_Game : public Game
{
    private:
        vector<Player *> players;
    public:

        void Pong_Game() {}
        void On_Key_Down(int key) 
        { 
           for(p : players) {
               Player::moves m =  p->On_key_down(); 
               ...  
            }
        }
        ... other event handlers here ... 
};
```

(This is just quickly hacked up - the "moves" may perhaps be better placed somewhere else, and the exact structure is just "what I could think of right now" - you probably need a `class Player_A_Pong : public Player_A` or some such to deal with the specifics of "player A's racket is here, player B's racket is here..." - although there are probably other ways to deal with that too).

Comment: Thank you for the answer but what can I do if I want to add more than one eventhandler to an event?

Comment: Please describe the scenario you are looking for, where you have more than one event handler...

Comment: Sorry for my bad description. I have adjusted my example and I hope it is now more clear what my purpose and my problem is.

Comment: But you could just as well solve that by calling the relevant functions PlayerA and PlayerB inside `On_Key_Event` in the `Pong_Game` class. Using function pointers here doesn't give you any benefit. Virtual functions is how you SHOULD solve this sort of problem.

Comment: OK but I'm aiming to implement the player in a seperate class. But wait, I guess I have a design issue here. You are right.